# Throwing the Exception But Using the Finally Block

Tags: java, exception-handling

Does this piece of code make sense? The idea is to throw any exceptions that may occur but always run the finally block to close the streams.

```
private void streamToFile(HttpResponse transferResponse) throws Exception {
    OutputStream output = null;
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new BufferedInputStream(transferResponse.getEntity().getContent());
        output = new FileOutputStream(transferFile);
        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024*10;
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            output.write(data, 0, count);
            publishProgress(count);
            remainingBytes = remainingBytes - count;
        }
    } finally {
        input.close();
        output.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what a `finally` block is for.

Comment: It runs the code in all circumstances. ie weather the exception is thrown or not

Comment: My comment wasn’t a question, it was a statement.

Comment: Sorry Konrad, its not so clear. What is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [`closeQuietly`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.io.InputStream%29) methods of `IOUtils` ([Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/)) (or similar ones) for input streams. It ignores exceptions and accepts `null` values.

Its implementation is just a few lines of code, so you can copy it directly to your Android application without the jar file:

```
public static void closeQuietly(Closeable closeable) {
    try {
        if (closeable != null) {
            closeable.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // ignore
    }
}
```

You could also create a close method for ouput streams:

```
public static void closeQuietly(OutputStream stream) throws IOException {
    if (stream != null) {
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

Both methods accept `null` values which means that you can call them with `null`, `closeQuietly` and `close` will handle that and you don't have to check `null` values in the `finally` block:

```
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        closeQuietly(input);
    }
    close(output);
}
```

Instead of this the following is completely enough:

```
} finally {
    closeQuietly(input);
    close(output);
}
```

It's much simpler.

`closeQuietly` ignores exceptions which means that it catches them but don't do anything with them. Notice the empty `catch` block:

```
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // ignore
    }
```

It ensures that if `closeable.close()` throws an `IOException` the `close(output)` will run and it will close the `output` stream too.

I'm a little bit paranoid about this so I always put a logging statement to the catch block:

```
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        logger.warn("Could not close the stream", ioe);
    }
```

To be honest, I've never seen this exception, so I think it's safe to left this block empty.

Ignoring `IOException`s of output streams could be dangerous: you might miss a bug and get a corrupted output file.

Comment: its actually Android so thats not really an option

Comment: @jiduvah: check the update, please.

Comment: what is the point of this code? You mentioned that I should use closeQuietly methods as it ignores exceptions and accepts null. But here you are catching an exception and checking for null

Comment: ... so you include this function, and call it from your `finally` blocks - instead of checking for nulls and exceptions and calling `.close()`. Seems clear enough for me - not for you?

Comment: Ah because in my code if the .close() throws an exception it will be passed up. I didn't think about that

Comment: You should NOT use `closeQuietly`, surely not for outputs streams, as it's [unsafe](http://goo.gl/eTEoQp). [`Closer`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closer.html) is the replacement (or [`@Cleanup`](http://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup.html) if you can use Lombok).

Comment: @maaartinus: Thanks for catching it! I remember that I've pointed out an ignored outputstream.close() exception on a code review with a colleague a few months ago so it's fun that I did the same mistake here. Anyway, I've updated the answer. Thanks for the `Closer` link too, that was new to me. You could write it as an answer too (I would upvote it).

Comment: No, a single complete answer is better. I'm just missing here my [favorite solution](http://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup.html).

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is the right way to do it but you should check output and input variables for null value before calling on them the close() method.

Comment: ... and also change it to something like `try {close1(); } finally {close2()}`, so that both get executed.